# finding a specific formula to sort an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sequence, algebra

I was wondering if there were any mathematicians who could help me solve the following problem:

I am trying to turn the sequence of numbers 012345678 into 036147258.

The purpose is to sort the indices of a PHP array where no standard sorting function is viable.

This is as far as I have got:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arrayWithNineIndices); $i++)
{
    $j=($i%3)*3;
    echo $j;
    if($i%3===0) echo " <----";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

which outputs 036036036 vertically with markers on the zeros.

Ideally what I need is a mechanism to add one to the values that follow first marker, then two to the values that follow the second.

I have spent all morning trying, mainly with `(j=0; j<3; j++)` loops, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  for ($j = $i; isset($array[$j]); $j += 3) {
    $result[] = $array[$j];
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/bWufA3YT)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$str = "012345678";
list($a, $b, $c) = array_chunk(str_split($str), 3);
foreach ( array_map(null, $a, $b, $c) as $part ) {
    echo implode($part);
}
```

Output

```
036147258
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/6176)

For a universal function

```
echo autoShift("012345678", 3), PHP_EOL;
echo autoShift("0123456", 3), PHP_EOL;
echo autoShift("012345678", 2), PHP_EOL;
echo autoShift("0123", 2), PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
036147258
0361425
024681357
0213
```

Function Used

```
function autoShift($str, $shift = 3) {
    $args = array_chunk(str_split($str), $shift);
    array_unshift($args, null);
    return implode(array_map("implode", call_user_func_array("array_map", $args)));
}
```